# Proof involving well ordering

Tags: set-theory

Let $A,B$ be well ordered sets with corresponding well orderings $\leqslant $ and $\leqslant '$. If $A$ is order isomorphic with $B$ initial segment $B '$ and $B$ is order isomorphic with $A$ initial segment $A '$, prove that $A '=A$ and $B'=B$. We should be able to conclude that $A$ is order isomorphic with $B$.

Any ideas on how I should approach this problem? Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Let $f:A\to B$ be an order isomorphism mapping $A$ onto the initial segment $B'$, and let $g:B\to A$ be an order isomorphism mapping $B$ onto the initial segment $A'$.

- Show that $g\circ f:A\to A$ is an order isomorphism mapping $A$ onto an initial segment $A''=g[B']$ of $A$.
- Use the fact that $\langle A,\le\rangle$ is a well-order to show that $A''=A$: no well-order is order isomorphic to a proper initial segment.
- Deduce that $A=A'$, $B=B'$, and $A$ and $B$ are order isomorphic.